# Samsung Galaxy S3 stuck at Samsung Logo after custom rom

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-3, twrp, boot-loop, resurrection-remix-os

I had this Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3. Since Youtube didn't open as it required an update but the play store said it is up to date(i usually use it to watch youtube), I planned to install Resurrection Remix ROM(Android 7.1). I installed TWRP and installed the rom. It was successful, but it didn't boot. It was stuck on '**Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300**' boot and it didn't go from there. I tried many things like reflashing the rom, wiping cache but nothing worked. Can anyone help me, please?

Thank You.

**EDIT:** I just found that that the rom is unable to write-in /data but it is writable(i tried open gapps micro package and it wrote it

Comment: format userdata partition